# ReactJS Get data from firestore with a WHERE clause condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So this is my current code, I am able to get the chats from the firestore database and storing the data in `useChats` which is being called by other components.
This is working and data is returned.

My issue is when I am trying to perform a filter using where clause on 2 fields part of the collection.

What I'm trying to achieve is getting all the chats `where firstPartyUserId = 48 OR secondPartyFullName = 48`

**This is my firestore structure**

[image]

**This is the code that gets all the chats without filtering**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

const FirebaseChats = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
        // creds here
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const firestore = getFirestore(app);
  
  const chatsRef = collection(firestore, "chats");
  const useChats = () => useCollectionData(chatsRef, { idField: "id" });

  console.log(useChats)

  return {app, firestore, useChats, firebaseConfig}
}


export default FirebaseChats;
```

I have tried something like this but kept on returning undefined

```
const conditions = [
    where("firstPartyUserId", "==", 48),
    where("secondPartyFullName", "==", "48"),
  ];

  // Create a query with OR conditions
  const filteredQuery = query(chatsRef, ...conditions);

  // Use the query directly in the useCollectionData hook
  const [useChats] = useCollectionData(filteredQuery, { idField: "id" });

  console.log(useChats);
```

Comment: _TL;DR_... `query(chatsRef, or(...conditions))`

Comment: I was able to resolve using `const filteredChatsQuery = query(chatsRef, or(where("firstPartyUserId", "==", 48), where("secondPartyUserId", "==", 48)));`